# how can i access to html textbox and enter a value?

Tags: html, insert, textbox

I have a website.
for example:
https://www.google.com/
And I need to access the text box that has it and insert a string value.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the text box and edit the value by selecting the ID via Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("textboxID").value="NEW Value"; 
</script>
```

Comment: i need a code in python that can access to a website and change the value of the text box

Comment: Yeah you can. It would be similar to :
```
def  set_value():
    text.insert("NEW Value",value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on button click it will change the value =>

```
Name: <input type="text" id="myText" value="test">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myText").value = "New Value";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For google link is like this
https://www.google.com/search?q=text+to+search
in python you can do it like this

```
text = "text to search"
text = text.split(" ")
s="+"
s = s.join(text)
print("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + s)
```

this will print link now you get html of this link by using many libraries